# PHP bootstrap 4 modal delete button in each row

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4, sql-delete, delete-row

Good day! I got a error that says "Undefined variable: id".

I created a table which has a delete button in each row, when clicked pops up an modal and asks if I want to delete the row. But when ever I click on the delete button it says the error Undefined variable: id and doesn't delete the data.

Here's my table code:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $data->delete_multiple($id, $conn);

    }

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table1">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Faculty Code</th>
                                            <th>Last Name</th>
                                            <th>First Name</th>
                                            <th>Middle Name</th>
                                            <th>Position</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php  while ($row = $result -> fetch_object()): ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo  $row->Faculty_ID;?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->Faculty_Lastname ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->Faculty_Firstname ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->Faculty_Middlename?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->Position; ?></td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary text-muted" href="Faculty_edit.php?Faculty_ID=<?php echo $row->Faculty_ID;?>">Edit</a>
                                                <a type="button"  title="Delete Faculty" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_modal"  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" >Delete</button></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php if($row->Status=='Active') echo '<a href="#deactive_account" data-toggle="modal" data-id='.$row->Faculty_ID.' class="activate" style="color:green;">Active</a>'; ?>
                                                <?php if($row->Status=='Inactive') echo '<a href="#active_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id='.$row->Faculty_ID.' class="activate" style="color:red;">Inactive</a>'; ?>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

My modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete_modal" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <!-- Modal Header -->
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmaiton</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Modal body -->
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                              Are you sure you want to delete selected record?
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Modal footer -->
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">Yes</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Delete function code:

```
 function delete_multiple($id, $conn){


         $id = $_POST['delete'];
         $sql = "DELETE FROM faculty WHERE Faculty_ID=? ";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt->execute();    
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not passing the row id to the modal popup.

Add the faculty id to your delete button and add a unique class to it 'delete-faculty-btn'. Ref. to below line

```
<a type="button" data-fid="<?php echo  $row->Faculty_ID;?>" title="Delete Faculty" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_modal"  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger delete-faculty-btn" >Delete</button></td>
```

Change your modal popup footer to:-

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="" id="row-id-to-delete" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Yes</button>
                      </div>
```

And add the below Javascript Script:-

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-faculty-btn', function(){
    $("#row-id-to-delete").val($(this).data('fid'));
});
```

My assumption is that you have the submit button in your modal popup inside a HTML form.

Comment: Because you have not initialised the $id variable.
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$id = $_POST['delete'];
        $data->delete_multiple($id, $conn);

    }

Comment: Also, now you can delete the line "$id = $_POST['delete'];" from your function delete_multiple

Comment: Thank you so much @Ankur Sharma

Comment: My Pleasure :-)

Comment: was it working previously? Any error you are getting? do you have another modal popup for them?

Comment: Yes the status active and deactive was working properly.. Can I share you my codes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177447/discussion-between-jerico-and-ankur-sharma).